# How can I stop all this verbose output in maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I am running web browser automation using maven and have noticed all this verbose output. There are lots of people working on the project and no one is sure when the verbose output started appearing. Ideally I just want the cucumber test status and the output from writing to the console. The output is slowing down my execution and I want to get rid of it, here's an example of some of the output:

```
   "script": "return (function(){return (function(){var k=this;function l(a){return void 0!==a}function n(a){return\"string\"==typeof a}function aa(a,b){a=a.split(\".\");var c=k;a[0]in c||\"undefined\"==typeof c.execScript||c.execScript(\"var \"+a[0]);for(var d;a.length&&(d=a.shift());)!a.length&&l(b)?c
[d]=b:c[d]&&c[d]!==Object.prototype[d]?c=c[d]:c=c[d]={}}\nfunction ba(a){var b=typeof a;if(\"object\"==b)if(a){if(a instanceof Array)return\"array\";if(a instanceof Object)return b;var c=Object.prototype.toString.call(a);if(\"[object Window]\"==c)return\"object\";if(\"[object Array]\"==c||\"number\"==ty
peof a.length&&\"undefined\"!=typeof a.splice&&\"undefined\"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable(\"splice\"))return\"array\";if(\"[object Function]\"==c||\"undefined\"!=typeof a.call&&\"undefined\"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable(\"call\"))return\"function\"}e
lse return\"null\";\nelse if(\"function\"==b&&\"undefined\"==typeof a.call)return\"object\";return b}function ca(a,b,c){return a.call.apply(a.bind,arguments)}function da(a,b,c){if(!a)throw Error();if(2\u003Carguments.length){var d=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);return function(){var e=Array.pro
totype.slice.call(arguments);Array.prototype.unshift.apply(e,d);return a.apply(b,e)}}return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}\nfunction ea(a,b,c){Function.prototype.bind&&-1!=Function.prototype.bind.toString().indexOf(\"native code\")?ea=ca:ea=da;return ea.apply(null,arguments)}function fa(a,b){v
ar c=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return function(){var d=c.slice();d.push.apply(d,arguments);return a.apply(this,d)}}function t(a,b){function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c;a.prototype.constructor=a};/*\n\n The MIT License\n\n Copyright (c) 2007 Cybozu Labs, Inc.\n Copyright
(c) 2012 Google Inc.\n\n Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy\n of this software and associated documentation files (the \"Software\"), to\n deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the\n rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, d
istribute, sublicense, and/or\n sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is\n furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:\n\n The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in\n all copies or substantial portions of the Software.\n\n T
HE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED \"AS IS\", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR\n IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,\n FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE\n AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER\n
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING\n FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS\n IN THE SOFTWARE.\n*/\nfunction ha(a,b,c){this.a=a;this.b=b||1;this.f=c||1};var ia=Array.prototype.indexOf?function(a,b){return Array.prototype.indexOf.
call(a,b,void 0)}:function(a,b){if(n(a))return n(b)&&1==b.length?a.indexOf(b,0):-1;for(var c=0;c\u003Ca.length;c++)if(c in a&&a[c]===b)return c;return-1},u=Array.prototype.forEach?function(a,b){Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,b,void 0)}:function(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=n(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e\u003Cc
;e++)e in d&&b.call(void 0,d[e],e,a)},ja=Array.prototype.filter?function(a,b){return Array.prototype.filter.call(a,b,void 0)}:function(a,\nb){for(var c=a.length,d=[],e=0,f=n(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,g=0;g\u003Cc;g++)if(g in f){var h=f[g];b.call(void 0,h,g,a)&&(d[e++]=h)}return d},ka=Array.prototype.reduce?fun
ction(a,b,c){return Array.prototype.reduce.call(a,b,c)}:function(a,b,c){var d=c;u(a,function(e,f){d=b.call(void 0,d,e,f,a)});return d},la=Array.prototype.some?function(a,b){return Array.prototype.some.call(a,b,void 0)}:function(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=n(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e\u003Cc;e++)if(e in d&&b
.call(void 0,d[e],e,a))return!0;return!1},ma=Array.prototype.every?\nfunction(a,b){return Array.prototype.every.call(a,b,void 0)}:function(a,b){for(var c=a.length,d=n(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e\u003Cc;e++)if(e in d&&!b.call(void 0,d[e],e,a))return!1;return!0};function na(a,b){a:{for(var c=a.length,d=n(a)?
a.split(\"\"):a,e=0;e\u003Cc;e++)if(e in d&&b.call(void 0,d[e],e,a)){b=e;break a}b=-1}return 0>b?null:n(a)?a.charAt(b):a[b]}function oa(a){return Array.prototype.concat.apply([],arguments)}\nfunction pa(a,b,c){return 2>=arguments.length?Array.prototype.slice.call(a,b):Array.prototype.slice.call(a,b,c)};
var qa=String.prototype.trim?function(a){return a.trim()}:function(a){return/^[\\s\\xa0]*([\\s\\S]*?)[\\s\\xa0]*$/.exec(a)[1]};function ra(a,b){return a\u003Cb?-1:a>b?1:0};var v;a:{var sa=k.navigator;if(sa){var ta=sa.userAgent;if(ta){v=ta;break a}}v=\"\"}function x(a){return-1!=v.indexOf(a)};function ua
(){return x(\"Firefox\")||x(\"FxiOS\")}function va(){return(x(\"Chrome\")||x(\"CriOS\"))&&!x(\"Edge\")};function wa(a){return String(a).replace(/\\-([a-z])/g,function(b,c){return c.toUpperCase()})};function xa(){return x(\"iPhone\")&&!x(\"iPod\")&&!x(\"iPad\")};function ya(a,b){var c=za;return Object.pr
ototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c,a)?c[a]:c[a]=b(a)};var Aa=x(\"Opera\"),y=x(\"Trident\")||x(\"MSIE\"),Ba=x(\"Edge\"),Ca=x(\"Gecko\")&&!(-1!=v.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!x(\"Edge\"))&&!(x(\"Trident\")||x(\"MSIE\"))&&!x(\"Edge\"),Da=-1!=v.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!x(\"Edge\");function Ea()
{var a=k.document;return a?a.documentMode:void 0}var Fa;\na:{var Ga=\"\",Ha=function(){var a=v;if(Ca)return/rv:([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(Ba)return/Edge\\/([\\d\\.]+)/.exec(a);if(y)return/\\b(?:MSIE|rv)[: ]([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(Da)return/WebKit\\/(\\S+)/.exec(a);if(Aa)return/(?:Version)[ \\/]
?(\\S+)/.exec(a)}();Ha&&(Ga=Ha?Ha[1]:\"\");if(y){var Ia=Ea();if(null!=Ia&&Ia>parseFloat(Ga)){Fa=String(Ia);break a}}Fa=Ga}var za={};\nfunction Ja(a){return ya(a,function(){for(var b=0,c=qa(String(Fa)).split(\".\"),d=qa(String(a)).split(\".\"),e=Math.max(c.length,d.length),f=0;0==b&&f\u003Ce;f++){var g=c
[f]||\"\",h=d[f]||\"\";do{g=/(\\d*)(\\D*)(.*)/.exec(g)||[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"];h=/(\\d*)(\\D*)(.*)/.exec(h)||[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"];if(0==g[0].length&&0==h[0].length)break;b=ra(0==g[1].length?0:parseInt(g[1],10),0==h[1].length?0:parseInt(h[1],10))||ra(0==g[2].length,0==h[2].length)||ra(g[2],h[2]);g=g[3];h
=h[3]}while(0==b)}return 0\u003C=b})}var Ka;var La=k.document;\nKa=La&&y?Ea()||(\"CSS1Compat\"==La.compatMode?parseInt(Fa,10):5):void 0;var z=y&&!(9\u003C=Number(Ka)),Ma=y&&!(8\u003C=Number(Ka));function Na(a,b,c,d){this.a=a;this.nodeName=c;this.nodeValue=d;this.nodeType=2;this.parentNode=this.ownerElem
ent=b}function Oa(a,b){var c=Ma&&\"href\"==b.nodeName?a.getAttribute(b.nodeName,2):b.nodeValue;return new Na(b,a,b.nodeName,c)};function Pa(a){this.b=a;this.a=0}function Qa(a){a=a.match(Ra);for(var b=0;b\u003Ca.length;b++)Sa.test(a[b])&&a.splice(b,1);return new Pa(a)}var Ra=/\\$?(?:(?![0-9-\\.])(?:\\*|[
\\w-\\.]+):)?(?![0-9-\\.])(?:\\*|[\\w-\\.]+)|\\/\\/|\\.\\.|::|\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[!\u003C>]=|\\s+|./g,Sa=/^\\s/;function A(a,b){return a.b[a.a+(b||0)]}function B(a){return a.b[a.a++]}function Ta(a){return a.b.length\u003C=a.a};function Ua(a,b){this.x=l(a)?a:0;this.y=l(b)?b:0}Ua.
prototype.ceil=function(){this.x=Math.ceil(this.x);this.y=Math.ceil(this.y);return this};Ua.prototype.floor=function(){this.x=Math.floor(this.x);this.y=Math.floor(this.y);return this};Ua.prototype.round=function(){this.x=Math.round(this.x);this.y=Math.round(this.y);return this};function Va(a,b){this.wid
th=a;this.height=b}Va.prototype.aspectRatio=function(){return this.width/this.height};Va.prototype.ceil=function(){this.width=Math.ceil(this.width);this.height=Math.ceil(this.height);return this};Va.prototype.floor=function(){this.width=Math.floor(this.width);this.height=Math.floor(this.height);return t
his};Va.prototype.round=function(){this.width=Math.round(this.width);this.height=Math.round(this.height);return this};function Wa(a,b){if(!a||!b)return!1;if(a.contains&&1==b.nodeType)return a==b||a.contains(b);if(\"undefined\"!=typeof a.compareDocumentPosition)return a==b||!!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b
)&16);for(;b&&a!=b;)b=b.parentNode;return b==a}\nfunction Xa(a,b){if(a==b)return 0;if(a.compareDocumentPosition)return a.compareDocumentPosition(b)&2?1:-1;if(y&&!(9\u003C=Number(Ka))){if(9==a.nodeType)return-1;if(9==b.nodeType)return 1}if(\"sourceIndex\"in a||a.parentNode&&\"sourceIndex\"in a.parentNode
){var c=1==a.nodeType,d=1==b.nodeType;if(c&&d)return a.sourceIndex-b.sourceIndex;var e=a.parentNode,f=b.parentNode;return e==f?Ya(a,b):!c&&Wa(e,b)?-1*Za(a,b):!d&&Wa(f,a)?Za(b,a):(c?a.sourceIndex:e.sourceIndex)-(d?b.sourceIndex:f.sourceIndex)}d=C(a);c=d.createRange();\nc.selectNode(a);c.collapse(!0);a=d.
createRange();a.selectNode(b);a.collapse(!0);return c.compareBoundaryPoints(k.Range.START_TO_END,a)}function Za(a,b){var c=a.parentNode;if(c==b)return-1;for(;b.parentNode!=c;)b=b.parentNode;return Ya(b,a)}function Ya(a,b){for(;b=b.previousSibling;)if(b==a)return-1;return 1}function C(a){return 9==a.node
Type?a:a.ownerDocument||a.document}function $a(a,b){a&&(a=a.parentNode);for(var c=0;a;){if(b(a))return a;a=a.parentNode;c++}return null}\nfunction ab(a){this.a=a||k.document||document}ab.prototype.getElementsByTagName=function(a,b){return(b||this.a).getElementsByTagName(String(a))};function E(a){var b=n
ull,c=a.nodeType;1==c&&(b=a.textContent,b=void 0==b||null==b?a.innerText:b,b=void 0==b||null==b?\"\":b);if(\"string\"!=typeof b)if(z&&\"title\"==a.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&1==c)b=a.text;else if(9==c||1==c){a=9==c?a.documentElement:a.firstChild;c=0;var d=[];for(b=\"\";a;){do 1!=a.nodeType&&(b+=a.nodeValue
),z&&\"title\"==a.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&(b+=a.text),d[c++]=a;while(a=a.firstChild);for(;c&&!(a=d[--c].nextSibling););}}else b=a.nodeValue;return b}\nfunction F(a,b,c){if(null===b)return!0;try{if(!a.getAttribute)return!1}catch(d){return!1}Ma&&\"class\"==b&&(b=\"className\");return null==c?!!a.getAttrib
ute(b):a.getAttribute(b,2)==c}function bb(a,b,c,d,e){return(z?cb:db).call(null,a,b,n(c)?c:null,n(d)?d:null,e||new G)}\nfunction cb(a,b,c,d,e){if(a instanceof eb||8==a.b||c&&null===a.b){var f=b.all;if(!f)return e;a=fb(a);if(\"*\"!=a&&(f=b.getElementsByTagName(a),!f))return e;if(c){for(var g=[],h=0;b=f[h+
+];)F(b,c,d)&&g.push(b);f=g}for(h=0;b=f[h++];)\"*\"==a&&\"!\"==b.tagName||e.add(b);return e}gb(a,b,c,d,e);return e}\nfunction db(a,b,c,d,e){b.getElementsByName&&d&&\"name\"==c&&!y?(b=b.getElementsByName(d),u(b,function(f){a.a(f)&&e.add(f)})):b.getElementsByClassName&&d&&\"class\"==c?(b=b.getElementsByCl
assName(d),u(b,function(f){f.className==d&&a.a(f)&&e.add(f)})):a instanceof H?gb(a,b,c,d,e):b.getElementsByTagName&&(b=b.getElementsByTagName(a.f()),u(b,function(f){F(f,c,d)&&e.add(f)}));return e}\nfunction hb(a,b,c,d,e){var f;if((a instanceof eb||8==a.b||c&&null===a.b)&&(f=b.childNodes)){var g=fb(a);if
(\"*\"!=g&&(f=ja(f,function(h){return h.tagName&&h.tagName.toLowerCase()==g}),!f))return e;c&&(f=ja(f,function(h){return F(h,c,d)}));u(f,function(h){\"*\"==g&&(\"!\"==h.tagName||\"*\"==g&&1!=h.nodeType)||e.add(h)});return e}return ib(a,b,c,d,e)}function ib(a,b,c,d,e){for(b=b.firstChild;b;b=b.nextSibling
)F(b,c,d)&&a.a(b)&&e.add(b);return e}\nfunction gb(a,b,c,d,e){for(b=b.firstChild;b;b=b.nextSibling)F(b,c,d)&&a.a(b)&&e.add(b),gb(a,b,c,d,e)}function fb(a){if(a instanceof H){if(8==a.b)return\"!\";if(null===a.b)return\"*\"}return a.f()};function G(){this.b=this.a=null;this.l=0}function jb(a){this.f=a;thi
s.a=this.b=null}function lb(a,b){if(!a.a)return b;if(!b.a)return a;var c=a.a;b=b.a;for(var d=null,e,f=0;c&&b;){e=c.f;var g=b.f;e==g||e instanceof Na&&g instanceof Na&&e.a==g.a?(e=c,c=c.a,b=b.a):0\u003CXa(c.f,b.f)?(e=b,b=b.a):(e=c,c=c.a);(e.b=d)?d.a=e:a.a=e;d=e;f++}for(e=c||b;e;)e.b=d,d=d.a=e,f++,e=e.a;a
.b=d;a.l=f;return a}function mb(a,b){b=new jb(b);b.a=a.a;a.b?a.a.b=b:a.a=a.b=b;a.a=b;a.l++}\nG.prototype.add=function(a){a=new jb(a);a.b=this.b;this.a?this.b.a=a:this.a=this.b=a;this.b=a;this.l++};function nb(a){return(a=a.a)?a.f:null}function ob(a){return(a=nb(a))?E(a):\"\"}function I(a,b){return new p
b(a,!!b)}function pb(a,b){this.f=a;this.b=(this.s=b)?a.b:a.a;this.a=null}function J(a){var b=a.b;if(null==b)return null;var c=a.a=b;a.b=a.s?b.b:b.a;return c.f};function K(a){this.i=a;this.b=this.g=!1;this.f=null}function L(a){return\"\\n  \"+a.toString().split(\"\\n\").join(\"\\n  \")}function qb(a,b){a
.g=b}fun15:50:14.984 [AsyncHttpClient-timer-1-1] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Entry count for : http://localhost:58784 : 1
ction rb(a,b){a.b=b}function O(a,b){a=a.a(b);return a instanceof G?+ob(a):+a}function P(a,b){a=a.a(b);return a instanceof G?ob(a):\"\"+a}function sb(a,b){a=a.a(b);return a instanceof G?!!a.l:!!a};function tb(a,b,c){K.call(this,a.i);this.c=a;this.h=b;this.o=c;this.g=b.g||c.g;this.b=b.b||c.b;this.c==ub&&(
c.b||c.g||4==c.i||0==c.i||!b.f?b.b||b.g||4==b.i||0==b.i||!c.f||(this.f={name:c.f.name,u:b}):this.f={name:b.f.name,u:c})}t(tb,K);\nfunction vb(a,b,c,d,e){b=b.a(d);c=c.a(d);var f;if(b instanceof G&&c instanceof G){b=I(b);for(d=J(b);d;d=J(b))for(e=I(c),f=J(e);f;f=J(e))if(a(E(d),E(f)))return!0;return!1}if(b
 instanceof G||c instanceof G){b instanceof G?(e=b,d=c):(e=c,d=b);f=I(e);for(var g=typeof d,h=J(f);h;h=J(f)){switch(g){case \"number\":h=+E(h);break;case \"boolean\":h=!!E(h);break;case \"string\":h=E(h);break;default:throw Error(\"Illegal primitive type for comparison.\");}if(e==b&&a(h,d)||e==c&&a(d,h)
)return!0}return!1}return e?\"boolean\"==\ntypeof b||\"boolean\"==typeof c?a(!!b,!!c):\"number\"==typeof b||\"number\"==typeof c?a(+b,+c):a(b,c):a(+b,+c)}tb.prototype.a=function(a){return this.c.m(this.h,this.o,a)};tb.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Binary Expression: \"+this.c;a+=L(this.h);return
 a+=L(this.o)};function wb(a,b,c,d){this.H=a;this.C=b;this.i=c;this.m=d}wb.prototype.toString=function(){return this.H};var xb={};\nfunction Q(a,b,c,d){if(xb.hasOwnProperty(a))throw Error(\"Binary operator already created: \"+a);a=new wb(a,b,c,d);return xb[a.toString()]=a}Q(\"div\",6,1,function(a,b,c){r
eturn O(a,c)/O(b,c)});Q(\"mod\",6,1,function(a,b,c){return O(a,c)%O(b,c)});Q(\"*\",6,1,function(a,b,c){return O(a,c)*O(b,c)});Q(\"+\",5,1,function(a,b,c){return O(a,c)+O(b,c)});Q(\"-\",5,1,function(a,b,c){return O(a,c)-O(b,c)});Q(\"\u003C\",4,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){return d\u003Ce},a,
b,c)});\nQ(\">\",4,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){return d>e},a,b,c)});Q(\"\u003C=\",4,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){return d\u003C=e},a,b,c)});Q(\">=\",4,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){return d>=e},a,b,c)});var ub=Q(\"=\",3,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){ret
urn d==e},a,b,c,!0)});Q(\"!=\",3,2,function(a,b,c){return vb(function(d,e){return d!=e},a,b,c,!0)});Q(\"and\",2,2,function(a,b,c){return sb(a,c)&&sb(b,c)});Q(\"or\",1,2,function(a,b,c){return sb(a,c)||sb(b,c)});function yb(a,b){if(b.a.length&&4!=a.i)throw Error(\"Primary expression must evaluate to node
set if filter has predicate(s).\");K.call(this,a.i);this.c=a;this.h=b;this.g=a.g;this.b=a.b}t(yb,K);yb.prototype.a=function(a){a=this.c.a(a);return zb(this.h,a)};yb.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Filter:\"+L(this.c);return a+=L(this.h)};function Ab(a,b){if(b.length\u003Ca.B)throw Error(\"Function
 \"+a.j+\" expects at least\"+a.B+\" arguments, \"+b.length+\" given\");if(null!==a.A&&b.length>a.A)throw Error(\"Function \"+a.j+\" expects at most \"+a.A+\" arguments, \"+b.length+\" given\");a.G&&u(b,function(c,d){if(4!=c.i)throw Error(\"Argument \"+d+\" to function \"+a.j+\" is not of type Nodeset:
\"+c);});K.call(this,a.i);this.v=a;this.c=b;qb(this,a.g||la(b,function(c){return c.g}));rb(this,a.F&&!b.length||a.D&&!!b.length||la(b,function(c){return c.b}))}\nt(Ab,K);Ab.prototype.a=function(a){return this.v.m.apply(null,oa(a,this.c))};Ab.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Function: \"+this.v;if(t
his.c.length){var b=ka(this.c,function(c,d){return c+L(d)},\"Arguments:\");a+=L(b)}return a};function Bb(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){this.j=a;this.i=b;this.g=c;this.F=d;this.D=!1;this.m=e;this.B=f;this.A=l(g)?g:f;this.G=!!h}Bb.prototype.toString=function(){return this.j};var Cb={};\nfunction R(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){if(
Cb.hasOwnProperty(a))throw Error(\"Function already created: \"+a+\".\");Cb[a]=new Bb(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)}R(\"boolean\",2,!1,!1,function(a,b){return sb(b,a)},1);R(\"ceiling\",1,!1,!1,function(a,b){return Math.ceil(O(b,a))},1);R(\"concat\",3,!1,!1,function(a,b){return ka(pa(arguments,1),function(c,d){return
 c+P(d,a)},\"\")},2,null);R(\"contains\",2,!1,!1,function(a,b,c){b=P(b,a);a=P(c,a);return-1!=b.indexOf(a)},2);R(\"count\",1,!1,!1,function(a,b){return b.a(a).l},1,1,!0);\nR(\"false\",2,!1,!1,function(){return!1},0);R(\"floor\",1,!1,!1,function(a,b){return Math.floor(O(b,a))},1);R(\"id\",4,!1,!1,function
(a,b){function c(h){if(z){var m=e.all[h];if(m){if(m.nodeType&&h==m.id)return m;if(m.length)return na(m,function(w){return h==w.id})}return null}return e.getElementById(h)}var d=a.a,e=9==d.nodeType?d:d.ownerDocument;a=P(b,a).split(/\\s+/);var f=[];u(a,function(h){h=c(h);!h||0\u003C=ia(f,h)||f.push(h)});f
.sort(Xa);var g=new G;u(f,function(h){g.add(h)});return g},1);\nR(\"lang\",2,!1,!1,function(){return!1},1);R(\"last\",1,!0,!1,function(a){if(1!=arguments.length)throw Error(\"Function last expects ()\");return a.f},0);R(\"local-name\",3,!1,!0,function(a,b){return(a=b?nb(b.a(a)):a.a)?a.localName||a.nodeN
ame.toLowerCase():\"\"},0,1,!0);R(\"name\",3,!1,!0,function(a,b){return(a=b?nb(b.a(a)):a.a)?a.nodeName.toLowerCase():\"\"},0,1,!0);R(\"namespace-uri\",3,!0,!1,function(){return\"\"},0,1,!0);\nR(\"normalize-space\",3,!1,!0,function(a,b){return(b?P(b,a):E(a.a)).replace(/[\\s\\xa0]+/g,\" \").replace(/^\\s+
|\\s+$/g,\"\")},0,1);R(\"not\",2,!1,!1,function(a,b){return!sb(b,a)},1);R(\"number\",1,!1,!0,function(a,b){return b?O(b,a):+E(a.a)},0,1);R(\"position\",1,!0,!1,function(a){return a.b},0);R(\"round\",1,!1,!1,function(a,b){return Math.round(O(b,a))},1);R(\"starts-with\",2,!1,!1,function(a,b,c){b=P(b,a);a=
P(c,a);return 0==b.lastIndexOf(a,0)},2);R(\"string\",3,!1,!0,function(a,b){return b?P(b,a):E(a.a)},0,1);\nR(\"string-length\",1,!1,!0,function(a,b){return(b?P(b,a):E(a.a)).length},0,1);R(\"substring\",3,!1,!1,function(a,b,c,d){c=O(c,a);if(isNaN(c)||Infinity==c||-Infinity==c)return\"\";d=d?O(d,a):Infinit
y;if(isNaN(d)||-Infinity===d)return\"\";c=Math.round(c)-1;var e=Math.max(c,0);a=P(b,a);return Infinity==d?a.substring(e):a.substring(e,c+Math.round(d))},2,3);R(\"substring-after\",3,!1,!1,function(a,b,c){b=P(b,a);a=P(c,a);c=b.indexOf(a);return-1==c?\"\":b.substring(c+a.length)},2);\nR(\"substring-before
\",3,!1,!1,function(a,b,c){b=P(b,a);a=P(c,a);a=b.indexOf(a);return-1==a?\"\":b.substring(0,a)},2);R(\"sum\",1,!1,!1,function(a,b){a=I(b.a(a));b=0;for(var c=J(a);c;c=J(a))b+=+E(c);return b},1,1,!0);R(\"translate\",3,!1,!1,function(a,b,c,d){b=P(b,a);c=P(c,a);var e=P(d,a);a={};for(d=0;d\u003Cc.length;d++){
var f=c.charAt(d);f in a||(a[f]=e.charAt(d))}c=\"\";for(d=0;d\u003Cb.length;d++)f=b.charAt(d),c+=f in a?a[f]:f;return c},3);R(\"true\",2,!1,!1,function(){return!0},0);function H(a,b){this.h=a;this.c=l(b)?b:null;this.b=null;switch(a){case \"comment\":this.b=8;break;case \"text\":this.b=3;break;case \"pro
cessing-instruction\":this.b=7;break;case \"node\":break;default:throw Error(\"Unexpected argument\");}}function Db(a){return\"comment\"==a||\"text\"==a||\"processing-instruction\"==a||\"node\"==a}H.prototype.a=function(a){return null===this.b||this.b==a.nodeType};H.prototype.f=function(){return this.h}
;\nH.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Kind Test: \"+this.h;null===this.c||(a+=L(this.c));return a};function Eb(a){K.call(this,3);this.c=a.substring(1,a.length-1)}t(Eb,K);Eb.prototype.a=function(){return this.c};Eb.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Literal: \"+this.c};function eb(a,b){this.j=a.t
oLowerCase();a=\"*\"==this.j?\"*\":\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\";this.c=b?b.toLowerCase():a}eb.prototype.a=function(a){var b=a.nodeType;if(1!=b&&2!=b)return!1;b=l(a.localName)?a.localName:a.nodeName;return\"*\"!=this.j&&this.j!=b.toLowerCase()?!1:\"*\"==this.c?!0:this.c==(a.namespaceURI?a.namespaceUR
I.toLowerCase():\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\")};eb.prototype.f=function(){return this.j};\neb.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Name Test: \"+(\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"==this.c?\"\":this.c+\":\")+this.j};function Fb(a){K.call(this,1);this.c=a}t(Fb,K);Fb.prototype.a=function(){return this.c
};Fb.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Number: \"+this.c};function Gb(a,b){K.call(this,a.i);this.h=a;this.c=b;this.g=a.g;this.b=a.b;1==this.c.length&&(a=this.c[0],a.w||a.c!=Hb||(a=a.o,\"*\"!=a.f()&&(this.f={name:a.f(),u:null})))}t(Gb,K);function Ib(){K.call(this,4)}t(Ib,K);Ib.prototype.a=function(a)
{var b=new G;a=a.a;9==a.nodeType?b.add(a):b.add(a.ownerDocument);return b};Ib.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Root Helper Expression\"};function Jb(){K.call(this,4)}t(Jb,K);Jb.prototype.a=function(a){var b=new G;b.add(a.a);return b};Jb.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Context Helper Expressio
n\"};\nfunction Kb(a){return\"/\"==a||\"//\"==a}Gb.prototype.a=function(a){var b=this.h.a(a);if(!(b instanceof G))throw Error(\"Filter expression must evaluate to nodeset.\");a=this.c;for(var c=0,d=a.length;c\u003Cd&&b.l;c++){var e=a[c],f=I(b,e.c.s);if(e.g||e.c!=Lb)if(e.g||e.c!=Mb){var g=J(f);for(b=e.a(
new ha(g));null!=(g=J(f));)g=e.a(new ha(g)),b=lb(b,g)}else g=J(f),b=e.a(new ha(g));else{for(g=J(f);(b=J(f))&&(!g.contains||g.contains(b))&&b.compareDocumentPosition(g)&8;g=b);b=e.a(new ha(g))}}return b};\nGb.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Path Expression:\"+L(th15:50:16.296 [AsyncHttpClient-timer
-1-1] DEBUG org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPool - Entry count for : http://localhost:58784 : 1
is.h);if(this.c.length){var b=ka(this.c,function(c,d){return c+L(d)},\"Steps:\");a+=L(b)}return a};function Nb(a,b){this.a=a;this.s=!!b}\nfunction zb(a,b,c){for(c=c||0;c\u003Ca.a.length;c++)for(var d=a.a[c],e=I(b),f=b.l,g,h=0;g=J(e);h++){var m=a.s?f-h:h+1;g=d.a(new ha(g,m,f));if(\"number\"==typeof g)m=m
==g;else if(\"string\"==typeof g||\"boolean\"==typeof g)m=!!g;else if(g instanceof G)m=0\u003Cg.l;else throw Error(\"Predicate.evaluate returned an unexpected type.\");if(!m){m=e;g=m.f;var w=m.a;if(!w)throw Error(\"Next must be called at least once before remove.\");var r=w.b;w=w.a;r?r.a=w:g.a=w;w?w.b=r
:g.b=r;g.l--;m.a=null}}return b}\nNb.prototype.toString=function(){return ka(this.a,function(a,b){return a+L(b)},\"Predicates:\")};function Ob(a,b,c,d){K.call(this,4);this.c=a;this.o=b;this.h=c||new Nb([]);this.w=!!d;b=this.h;b=0\u003Cb.a.length?b.a[0].f:null;a.I&&b&&(a=b.name,a=z?a.toLowerCase():a,this
.f={name:a,u:b.u});a:{a=this.h;for(b=0;b\u003Ca.a.length;b++)if(c=a.a[b],c.g||1==c.i||0==c.i){a=!0;break a}a=!1}this.g=a}t(Ob,K);\nOb.prototype.a=function(a){var b=a.a,c=this.f,d=null,e=null,f=0;c&&(d=c.name,e=c.u?P(c.u,a):null,f=1);if(this.w)if(this.g||this.c!=Pb)if(b=I((new Ob(Qb,new H(\"node\"))).a(a
)),c=J(b))for(a=this.m(c,d,e,f);null!=(c=J(b));)a=lb(a,this.m(c,d,e,f));else a=new G;else a=bb(this.o,b,d,e),a=zb(this.h,a,f);else a=this.m(a.a,d,e,f);return a};Ob.prototype.m=function(a,b,c,d){a=this.c.v(this.o,a,b,c);return a=zb(this.h,a,d)};\nOb.prototype.toString=function(){var a=\"Step:\"+L(\"Opera
tor: \"+(this.w?\"//\":\"/\"));this.c.j&&(a+=L(\"Axis: \"+this.c));a+=L(this.o);if(this.h.a.length){var b=ka(this.h.a,function(c,d){return c+L(d)},\"Predicates:\");a+=L(b)}return a};function Rb(a,b,c,d){this.j=a;this.v=b;this.s=c;this.I=d}Rb.prototype.toString=function(){return this.j};var Sb={};functio
n S(a,b,c,d){if(Sb.hasOwnProperty(a))throw Error(\"Axis already created: \"+a);b=new Rb(a,b,c,!!d);return Sb[a]=b}\nS(\"ancestor\",function(a,b){for(var c=new G;b=b.parentNode;)a.a(b)&&mb(c,b);return c},!0);S(\"ancestor-or-self\",function(a,b){var c=new G;do a.a(b)&&mb(c,b);while(b=b.parentNode);return
c},!0);\nvar Hb=S(\"attribute\",function(a,b){var c=new G,d=a.f();if(\"style\"==d&&z&&b.style)return c.add(new Na(b.style,b,\"style\",b.style.cssText)),c;var e=b.attributes;if(e)if(a instanceof H&&null===a.b||\"*\"==d)for(a=0;d=e[a];a++)z?d.nodeValue&&c.add(Oa(b,d)):c.add(d);else(d=e.getNamedItem(d))&&(
z?d.nodeValue&&c.add(Oa(b,d)):c.add(d));return c},!1),Pb=S(\"child\",function(a,b,c,d,e){return(z?hb:ib).call(null,a,b,n(c)?c:null,n(d)?d:null,e||new G)},!1,!0);S(\"descendant\",bb,!1,!0);\nvar Qb=S(\"descendant-or-self\",function(a,b,c,d){var e=new G;F(b,c,d)&&a.a(b)&&e.add(b);return bb(a,b,c,d,e)},!1,
!0),Lb=S(\"following\",function(a,b,c,d){var e=new G;do for(var f=b;f=f.nextSibling;)F(f,c,d)&&a.a(f)&&e.add(f),e=bb(a,f,c,d,e);while(b=b.parentNode);return e},!1,!0);S(\"following-sibling\",function(a,b){for(var c=new G;b=b.nextSibling;)a.a(b)&&c.add(b);return c},!1);S(\"namespace\",function(){return n
ew G},!1);\nvar Tb=S(\"parent\",function(a,b){var c=new G;if(9==b.nodeType)return c;if(2==b.nodeType)return c.add(b.ownerElement),c;b=b.parentNode;a.a(b)&&c.add(b);return c},!1),Mb=S(\"preceding\",function(a,b,c,d){var e=new G,f=[];do f.unshift(b);while(b=b.parentNode);for(var g=1,h=f.length;g\u003Ch;g+
+){var m=[];for(b=f[g];b=b.previousSibling;)m.unshift(b);for(var w=0,r=m.length;w\u003Cr;w++)b=m[w],F(b,c,d)&&a.a(b)&&e.add(b),e=bb(a,b,c,d,e)}return e},!0,!0);\nS(\"preceding-sibling\",function(a,b){for(var c=new G;b=b.previousSibling;)a.a(b)&&mb(c,b);return c},!0);var Ub=S(\"self\",function(a,b){var c
=new G;a.a(b)&&c.add(b);return c},!1);function Vb(a){K.call(this,1);this.c=a;this.g=a.g;this.b=a.b}t(Vb,K);Vb.prototype.a=function(a){return-O(this.c,a)};Vb.prototype.toString=function(){return\"Unary Expression: -\"+L(this.c)};function Wb(a){K.call(this,4);this.c=a;qb(this,la(this.c,function(b){return
b.g}));rb(this,la(this.c,function(b){return b.b}))}t(Wb,K);Wb.prototype.a=function(a){var b=new G;u(this.c,function(c){c=c.a(a);if(!(c instanceof G))throw Error(\"Path expression must evaluate to NodeSet.\");b=lb(b,c)});return b};Wb.prototype.toString=function(){return ka(this.c,function(a,b){return a+L
(b)},\"Union Expression:\")};function Xb(a,b){this.a=a;this.b=b}function Yb(a){for(var b,c=[];;){T(a,\"Missing right hand side of binary expression.\");b=Zb(a);var d=B(a.a);if(!d)break;var e=(d=xb[d]||null)&&d.C;if(!e){a.a.a--;break}for(;c.length&&e\u003C=c[c.length-1].C;)b=new tb(c.pop(),c.pop(),b);c.p
ush(b,d)}for(;c.length;)b=new tb(c.pop(),c.pop(),b);return b}function T(a,b){if(Ta(a.a))throw Error(b);}function $b(a,b){a=B(a.a);if(a!=b)throw Error(\"Bad token, expected: \"+b+\" got: \"+a);}\nfunction cc(a){a=B(a.a);if(\")\"!=a)throw Error(\"Bad token: \"+a);}function dc(a){a=B(a.a);if(2>a.length)thr
ow Error(\"Unclosed literal string\");return new Eb(a)}\nfunction ec(a){var b=[];if(Kb(A(a.a))){var c=B(a.a);var d=A(a.a);if(\"/\"==c&&(Ta(a.a)||\".\"!=d&&\"..\"!=d&&\"@\"!=d&&\"*\"!=d&&!/(?![0-9])[\\w]/.test(d)))return new Ib;d=new Ib;T(a,\"Missing next location step.\");c=fc(a,c);b.push(c)}else{a:{c=A
(a.a);d=c.charAt(0);switch(d){case \"$\":throw Error(\"Variable reference not allowed in HTML XPath\");case \"(\":B(a.a);c=Yb(a);T(a,'unclosed \"(\"');$b(a,\")\");break;case '\"':case \"'\":c=dc(a);break;default:if(isNaN(+c))if(!Db(c)&&/(?![0-9])[\\w]/.test(d)&&\"(\"==A(a.a,1)){c=B(a.a);\nc=Cb[c]||null;
B(a.a);for(d=[];\")\"!=A(a.a);){T(a,\"Missing function argument list.\");d.push(Yb(a));if(\",\"!=A(a.a))break;B(a.a)}T(a,\"Unclosed function argument list.\");cc(a);c=new Ab(c,d)}else{c=null;break a}else c=new Fb(+B(a.a))}\"[\"==A(a.a)&&(d=new Nb(gc(a)),c=new yb(c,d))}if(c)if(Kb(A(a.a)))d=c;else return
c;else c=fc(a,\"/\"),d=new Jb,b.push(c)}for(;Kb(A(a.a));)c=B(a.a),T(a,\"Missing next location step.\"),c=fc(a,c),b.push(c);return new Gb(d,b)}\nfunction fc(a,b){if(\"/\"!=b&&\"//\"!=b)throw Error('Step op should be \"/\" or \"//\"');if(\".\"==A(a.a)){var c=new Ob(Ub,new H(\"node\"));B(a.a);return c}if(\
"..\"==A(a.a))return c=new Ob(Tb,new H(\"node\")),B(a.a),c;if(\"@\"==A(a.a)){var d=Hb;B(a.a);T(a,\"Missing attribute name\")}else if(\"::\"==A(a.a,1)){if(!/(?![0-9])[\\w]/.test(A(a.a).charAt(0)))throw Error(\"Bad token: \"+B(a.a));var e=B(a.a);d=Sb[e]||null;if(!d)throw

Request DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
POST /session/9182a3b9b367201e4bf5ce781ece3893/execute/sync HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: selenium/4.0.0-alpha-6 (java windows)
Content-Length: 49163
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
host: localhost:21110
accept: */*
```

The top set of output I believe comes from executing javascript to click elements on a page and the output at the bottom comes from a library called netty that logs API requests. Is there anyway to remove this output or the libraries that cause it using maven?

Comment: How is this related to Maven?

Comment: The test is executed in the command line using mvn test. I assume the output is caused by maven

Comment: This output is caused by tests not by Maven.

Comment: @KieranMarriott I see that you're using an (probably latest?) alpha version of selenium. Have you already checked if you get the same output with the previous one?

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: @LorenzoOrsatti It was an alpha version that was causing it, thank you so much